# ANSI C: Anonymous pointer in struct to array of strings - problems?

Tags: arrays, string, pointers

I must be missing something obvious...

I'd like to have an empty pointer to array of strings in my struct :

```
typedef struct SCR_SETTEXT_DESC_S
{
uint_8  Value;           //Current value - copy made prior function call
char *Strings;      // Pointer to array of strings
} SCR_SETTXT_DESC;
```

Then I'd like to use this struct and assign real array of strings :

```
SCR_SETTXT_DESC ScrSetTxtDesc;

char ScreenSetTxt_strings[4][20];
strcpy(ScreenSetTxt_strings[0], "choice1");
strcpy(ScreenSetTxt_strings[1], "choice2");
strcpy(ScreenSetTxt_strings[2], "choice3");

ScrSetTxtDesc.Strings = ScreenSetTxt_strings;
```

Here I get error :

> Error[Pe513]: a value of type "char (*)[20]" cannot be assigned to an
>   entity of type "char *"

What am I doing wrong ?

I'd like to use it like this :

```
printf("%s",ScrSetTxtDesc.Strings[0]);
```

Thanks in advance,

Bul.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating an array of strings, but a single string (char*).

If you want to have an array of strings, use

```
char **Strings;
```

You would then need to initialize your array using `malloc`.

The error happens because you limit a single string to 20 char ( `char[20]`), which is incompatible to `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

`SCR_SETTEXT_DESC.Strings` is a pointer-to-char (`char *`), whereas the `ScreenSetTxt_strings` array decays into a pointer-to-array-of-20-`char`s. Those are incompatible types.

Depending on what your actual requirement is, you can either declare the struct member as `char (*Strings)[20]`, or you can obtain a pointer to the first character in the first array of the array:

```
ScrSetTxtDesc.Strings = &ScreenSetTxt_strings[0][0];
```

Note that if you want to pass this structure around functions, you should not be assigning a pointer to a function-scope automatic variable, since that pointer is invalidated when the function returns.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. Now compiles, but strings are flatten to single index (so I have to access strings with index*20... Can I do this better - so I can retain original array of strings ?